# Is it possible to edit Question without notify owner?

Tags: discussion, editing

My question was edited by other person who have high reputation. But I didn't get ant notification regarding to this change. Before days the edit will be shows to me and after I accepted only the edit will be updated in my question.

I want to know Is it possible to edit my question without giving me any notification ?

The Question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498362/how-to-migrate-from-ubuntu-desktop-to-ubuntu-server).

Comment: You should have gotten a notification. It will appear as a message in your inbox. Whenever one of your posts is edited, you are informed. You probably just missed it.

Comment: @terdon no notification received in my inbox I have checked my inbox....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you get the editing privilege, you don't have to ask permission from the person asking the question.

For what it's worth it was a good edit.  He was generalizing the question to make it more useful for everyone in the future.  If it becomes the canonical question for that operation for all future releases, you should be thanking him for giving you rep rockets instead of complaining...

Comment: When the user got this privilege ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Comment: thank you, I must thank him... I know he helps me.. but i didn't got any notification, that's why I have asked here...